# Windows 10 constant 99% memory usage

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory

My Window 10 is continually using 99% of 32GB memory. Glancing at the windows Resource Manager, I can’t identify anything strange other than the “Memory Compression” using 1GB of memory. If I close Chrome, I still have about the same memory usage, which is 98%. I ran a BitDefender scan and found nothing unusual. I looked at superuser posts, but it did not help. Here is a screenshot of my Resource Monitor.

Any ideas what could be causing that?

[Resource Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4M1AT.jpg)

Comment: You can't disable Memory Compression on Windows 10, in reality if it wasn't for Memory Compression, your memory usage would be even higher.  Based on your screenshot Chrome is using a massive amount of memory.  Sadly, you have not provided enough information, to diagnose your high memory usage.

Comment: Do you have any actual problem or is the issue purely cosmetic? For example, are there performance issues?

Comment: @David, it's slowing my computer to an extent I can't do work on it.

Comment: @dobby Then you asked the wrong question. The question should be why your computer is slow and there should be a detailed description of what operations are slow, whether there's lots of disk I/O, and so on. Is it always slow? Does it get slower? Some problem description would be helpful and you didn't even *mention* the problem!

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound, As I was saying, it is a same sort of memory usage even before I start chrome.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidSchwartz. Most operations are slow, for example, MS word, excel... I thought it was related to not enough memory. If it something else, could you tell me how to get the stats to help you better?

Comment: @dobby - RAMMap would be more helpful.  However, we know nothing about your system configuration, your one screenshot shows high memory usage with numerous applications known to use lots of memory.  Are you getting out of memory exceptions?  It's possible you have a memory leak but you would have to diagnose that issue (based on what you provided we can't do that for you).

Comment: I second the suggestion to use RAMMap. A description of the problem would be helpful. Was this machine always slow? Did it suddenly get slow one day? Did it gradually get slower over time? Is it slow right after a restart? Is there anything unusual about what software or hardware it has or how it's used? And so on.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidSchwartz; no, this machine was not always slow. I was having performance issues for the last week or so. Right after the start, memory shots to 99% usage, and it stays there. Nothing unusual about the software I am using. Almost all software is well-known open-source and licensed vendors.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a software issue instead of a hardware issue. It looks like the virtual memory on windows has the wrong settings.

This slows down windows and makes the memory much higher than it should be. For example the settings for allocating virtual memory should be a multiple of 256 and a certain percentage of your physical memory.

The graphical user interface to choose the right settings is confusing where it's easy to click the wrong thing and it requires that the user do sums on a calculator before they type in the correct numbers. Instead I'll give you the command line commands to give it the optimum settings.

Open command prompt as **administrator**, from the start menu list of programs (from Windows Accesories), searching for command prompt on the start menu, typing in `cmd` on the `Run` window from Windows Key + `R`, or using Windows Key + `X` to open it.

You can tell if command prompt is running as administrator, because the word administrator will appear in the title bar of the window.

Run these commands in the correct order shown below or run the commands directly from the `tuneup2.bat` batch file by opening it in command prompt (the `2` in the file name is very important so don't download the wrong file). Your antivirus will most likely block the batch file but it's not a virus. [The download link and source is here.](https://www.tenforums.com/bsod-crashes-debugging/162488-batch-files-use-bsod-debugging.html#post2029409)

```
wmic recoveros get autoreboot
wmic recoveros set autoreboot = false
wmic recoveros get autoreboot

wmic recoveros get DebugInfoType
wmic recoveros set DebugInfoType = 7
wmic recoveros get DebugInfoType

wmic pagefile list /format:list

wmic Computersystem where name="%computername%" get AutomaticManagedPagefile
wmic Computersystem where name="%computername%" set AutomaticManagedPagefile=True
wmic Computersystem where name="%computername%" get AutomaticManagedPagefile

bcdedit /enum {badmemory}
```

Once all the commands have been executed, restart your computer to fully apply the changes. Command prompt saying the commands completed successfully is misleading, as a restart is actually required. Upon restart your problem should be solved with windows being faster, the memory not always at 99% or 100%, and with less programs freezing and crashing.